# How to update document property using REST (ListData.svc)?

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'd like to ask experts.
Does anyone know how to update document properties using REST (ListData.svc) ?

I could update list item properties using bellow code.But I got 500 internal error when using bellow for document library.

```
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
        HttpClient cl = new HttpClient(handler);

        cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfMatch.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.EntityTagHeaderValue.Any);

        JsonObject updateObj = new JsonObject();
        updateObj["title"] = JsonValue.CreateStringValue("titletest");
        updateObj["column01"] = JsonValue.CreateStringValue("columntest01");
        HttpContent jsonContent = new StringContent(updateObj.Stringify(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage res = cl.PutAsync("http://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/announcements(1)", jsonContent).Result;
```

Comment: title is always there in new library, but do you have `column01` in your library?

Comment: Sure. I have column01.

Comment: Not sure if the code is correct, but i notice you address the list 'announcements'. Please note that ListData.svc capitalises the first letter of the list name, so perhaps you could try Announcements?